# How i can perform mathematical operation on columns Index in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to do some mathematical operation Like:

```
B(1):=A(2) ,B(2):=A(2+10) and B(3):=A(2+2*10) ...
```

how i can do this?

Comment: That's the row index, not the column. `A` and `B` are the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INDEX`:

- `INDEX(B:B,1)=INDEX(A:A,2)`
- `INDEX(B:B,2)=INDEX(A:A,2+10)`
- `INDEX(B:B,3)=INDEX(A:A,2+2*10)`